# Error on running Shadow Fight 2

Tags: downloading, google-play-games

I downloaded a game called Shadow Fight 2 from uptodown.com, and after installing the game, when it is run, it gives me an error:

> Download failed because the resources could not be found.

Even after downloading about 45MB, it asks me to download more, but yet I want to play the game. Please help me fix the problem.

I tries rebooting, installing latest google play services and google play games apps, and also checking my internet connection. (I have a rooted phone, but I didn't unroot)

Comment: Why would you download app from some site when it's free on google play? If it's moded .apk then developer probably restricted apps which aren't downloaded from google play to download resources.

Answer (score 0):

Large games need extra files called asset files to be downloaded when you first launch the game. You just installed the APK. Do you think all those graphics, sounds, FX, stages, etc can be held in just 45MB?

So the developers may block apk from downloading asset files if it was download from another source than the Play Store.

You must download from the Play Store to be able to run the game.